# Special characters in Solr Query

Tags: php, solr, htmlspecialchars

I am working with Solr search extension, and i found this probleme with my input data, there are some special chart that Solr do not accept. so if i write somethig like (in french):

> "il faut être à l'aise"

=> i got

> "il faut être à l & #39; aise"

event if i've added

```
    $helper->escapeTerm(); 
    htmlspecialchars($filter, ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

I have the same output.

Do you have an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by I got? Did Solr return you that?

Comment: no, i make an var_dump() just before the solr quey

Comment: check http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#Why_don.27t_International_Characters_Work.3F and are also encoding the values returned correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just made `str_replace();` to solve this porblem! thanks